# Get Frame Source from WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, browser, save, frame

I wrote up a function to save sites source as my WebBrowser control navigates around. I cant save only the WebBrowser.DocumentText as that leaves out all frame content.

The issue I'm having now is accessing the frame content - I cant find which method/property contains it.

The following works with a simple WebBrowser control, simply put `saveWebsite(FilePath, WebBrowser1)` in the DocumentCompleted event.

Ive done this in VB.NET but am familiar with C#, so C# solutions good too

```
    Public Sub saveWebsite(ByVal sDirectory As String, ByVal oBrowser As WebBrowser)

    File.WriteAllText(sDirectory & "index.htm", oBrowser.DocumentText)

    'Now write a file for each frame - putting each file in its relative path'
    For Each oFrame As HtmlWindow In oBrowser.Document.Window.Frames
        oFI = New FileInfo(sDirectory & oBrowser.Url.MakeRelativeUri(oFrame.Url).ToString)
        oFI.Directory.Create()

        'ISSUE: This is the issue, unlike with oBrowser, there is no DocumentText property for oFrame.'
        'ISSUE: Ive tried several things like Body.InnerText/Html, Body.OuterText/HTML, etc.'
        File.WriteAllText(oFI.ToString, oFrame.WindowFrameElement.InnerText )
    Next oFrame
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After more experimenting, I just found a solution. However its dirty and I dont particularly like it.

Switching the last/issue line from `oFrame.WindowFrameElement.InnerText` to `oFrame.Document.All.Item(0).OuterHtml` seems to do the trick sometimes. This wont do anything about nested frames, but Im not really worried about that.

Anywho, if anyone has a cleaner solution to the above, please let me know. (Or even a more effective/efficient way of "saving all").

Edit: The following seems to work a bit better, but still not great. (I had a webpage that started with <% VBSCRIPT %> and thats all that got saved) `oFrame.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html").Item(0).OuterHtml`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing simlar problem, I wanted to acess all the text contend within a Frame in a page. Below code worked for me

```
Dim frame = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames(0) //Replace 0 with frame id if needed
Dim innderdiv= frame.Document.GetElementById("divContentLower")
Dim contents = innderdiv.InnerText
MsgBox(contents )
```

Here `divContentLover` is the id of an immediate child div within the frame. So the code returns its contents